# validates_exclusion_of for usernames used in pathways

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I am trying to prevent usernames from having specific characters so they can be used in pathways. Basically I want to use pathways such as www.mysite.com/profiles/username and allowing stuff like user.name or user/name will cause errors. I was originally think of using `validates_exclusion_of`, but am not sure if this allows to exclude characters rather than whole words. I am also wondering if it would be a better practice to whitelist rather than blacklist. For example, I could whitelist 0..9 and A..Z.

Does anyone know of any "standard" or best practice approaches to this?

Comment: Have you considered using any of these gems to help you out? http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_permalinks___slugs.html

Comment: @Rubish Gupta, thanks for the link. I'm good on the pathways, but actually just need to restrict which characters can be used for usernames. For example, a user could create a username of james/posts, which actually might be a valued path that I want to use for another route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard and best approach for this is to use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id). But if you don't want to increase dependencies of your project, and want to only allow alphanumeric:

```
validates :user_name, 
          :format => {:with => /^\w+$}, 
          :presence => true, 
          :uniqueness => true
```